# How to determine the stopping point of a loop when crawling a web-site

Tags: web, web-crawler

My program currently goes through pages of a website gathering information. How do I set my loop to end when I have visited all the websites pages?

Is there some way of knowing the amount of webpages in any site?
Or do I have compare a block of pages I have visited eg 10 and if the pages are checked in that order again i know its repeating itself.

I'm sure there has to be a better way of knowing when to stop.

Comment: Take a look at DFS algorithm.

Comment: Just add a `HashSet` holding the URLs of the sites you've already visited. If a site is already in this set, skip it.

Answer (score 2):

Keep track of pages visited ( may be keeping visited URL in a set) and when trying to scan a new page, check if it is already visited.

Answer (score 1):

[Breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

[Depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

Check these two algorithms. Think of the site as a graph
whose nodes are the pages and whose edges/arcs are the links
from one page to another. So two pages are neighboring
A **→** B, if there's a link from page A to page B.

Then just implement one of these two algorithms
(whichever you find more appropriate for your case).
Both of them have their respective stop conditions.

Your search in both cases should start with the root
page(s) which is usually `default.ext` or `index.ext` or
something similar (ext = html, asp, aspx, jsp, php, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to pre-process the website with a **[SitemapGenerator](https://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/wiki/SitemapGenerators)** and only visit the webpages included in the sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way of knowing the amount of webpages in any site

No. All you can do to examine a web-site is to make HTTP GET (or HEAD) requests and examine the response. That will tell you whether the URI is a valid identifier for a resource, and get you a representation of that resource. You can not know which requests will indicate a valid resource, nor can you practically generate all the possible URIs to perform an exhaustive search.

At best, all you can do is to start with a URI and find all the resources *reachable* from that URI, by examining resources that contain links to other resources, and then following those links.